# iOS: Can I use current speed to play sound?

Tags: ios

So I am planning to build a basic app that does the following:

- When app is turned on:
- track the speed
- once speed is over threshold
- play sound
- the 'sound' is randomly picked from an array of sound.

I know iOS is known for being restrictive so I've planned my app
using as less resources as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And? What doesn't work?

Comment: track the speed of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a YES/NO answer then the answer is YES, you can do all of those things...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Would it be possible for the app to stay on the background and keep alive and carry out it's operations?

Comment: You will be able to track the location, but if the app is in background, you cant' start palying a sound, it needs to be on the screen